# Does anyone have a full solution/walkthrough of how to use the perl Template module?

Tags: string, perl, template-engine

@neuhaus pointed out [new documentation](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Web.html#section_Dynamic_Content_Generation_Via_CGI_Script) to me on the template-toolkit.org site

Here is the code from CPAN that I have been trying to run/mess about with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib ('./t/lib/');

use strict;
use warnings;

use Template;



use Test::More tests => 1;



my $text = "This is string number [% num %] ."; 

my $vars = {
     num => "one",
 };

my $template = Template->new();

$template->process($text, $vars)
    || die "Template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";


ok(defined $text, 'Returns something');
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Template process failed: file error - This is string number [% num %] . : not found
```

I am just running it in a test file at the moment, in case you guy are wondering.

Comment: Re. "I have only seen answers in relation to Template::Toolkit which doesn't seem to be available on our system." (from before your edit) Template::Toolkit is simply the distribution that contains Template.pm. It's not a separate templating system.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. `use Template::Toolkit` doesn't work on this system. I have no idea why though...

Comment: It doesn't work because `use Template::Toolkit;` looks for the file Toolkit.pm inside the Template directory, but there is no Toolkit.pm. You have to do `use Template;`

Comment: `use Template::Toolkit` doesn't work on any system. There's no such module as Template::Toolkit. The main interface to the Template Toolkit is just called "Template" - it's the system that you're using.

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot , thanks for clearing that up

Comment: The only real idiot is the person to frightened to ask.

Comment: @PaulRussell: I think it's less than sensible of the author to name the module/package `Template` when it is known colloquially as *Template::Toolkit* and *TT*. Too late to change that now, obviously

Comment: @PaulRussell: Stack Exchange is different from regular forums or blogs. While it's fine to *add* clarifying information to your question, or to correct typing mistakes, it's inappropriate to morph your question so far from its original form, primarily because it usually makes nonsense out of comments and solutions posted before the changes. If you gain enlightenment from your original question but reach a new stumbling block then you should open a new question.

Comment: okay sorry. I thought that I should not be posting similar questions . I didn't want to spam stackoverflow with the same kind of code. I will post plenty of questions now separately no matter how minor they are. Thanks @Borodin . :)

Comment: I didn't mean to morph my question as much as I did . Thanks for hte heads up :)

Answer (score 3):

The definition of the `process()` method in the [Template documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template#process-template-vars-output-options) says this:

> The first parameter indicates the input template as one of: a filename
>   relative to `INCLUDE_PATH`, if defined; a reference to a text string
>   containing the template text; or a file handle reference (e.g.
>   `IO::Handle` or sub-class) or `GLOB` (e.g. `\*STDIN`), from which the
>   template can be read.

If you pass it a string, it is assumed to be the **name of a file containing the template**. If you want to pass it a string containing the actual template, then you need to pass a reference to a string.

So your line:

```
$template->process($text, $vars)
```

Needs to be:

```
$template->process(\$text, $vars)
```

The error message was a good clue to this. It was telling you that it couldn't find a file called "This is string number [% num %] .".

Answer (score 2):

Check out the tutorial at [template-toolkit.org](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Web.html)
especially the section
[*Dynamic Content Generation Via CGI Script*](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Web.html#section_Dynamic_Content_Generation_Via_CGI_Script)

Comment: That section seems very similar to what I want to do. But I am getting errors. I will update the code in my question now.

Answer (score 2):

You may find [`Template::Manual::Intro`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Manual::Intro) and [`Template::FAQ`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::FAQ) useful, and there are excellent tutorials in the package with `Template`

[`Template::Tutorial`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Tutorial) is a portal to

- [`Template::Tutorial::Web`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Tutorial::Web) *Generating Web Content Using the Template Toolkit*
- [`Template::Tutorial::Datafile`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Tutorial::Datafile) *Creating Data Output Files Using the Template Toolkit*

The module has its own web site at [`template-toolkit.org`](http://template-toolkit.org/) but the documentation there is just a mirror of the POD from the installation package